# How to access data from ViewController in subview?

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, subview, viewcontroller

I have a viewcontroller which contains an instance variable containing a dictionary object with a bunch of data. The view is fairly complex and contains several subviews that i instantiate and embed from seperate view files(To avoid having a thousand lines of UI code in the actual viewcontroller) - But how do these subviews, which exists in their own files, get access to my dictionary object from the viewcontroller?
So when im editing the DescriptionView.m file - How do i get access to the contents of the locationData dictionary object from the ViewController?

Hope you understand what i mean.

Here's a snippet from the ViewController:

CaseViewController.h

```
#import "DescriptionView.h"

@interface CaseViewController : UIViewController {
    NSDictionary *locationData;

    DescriptionView *descriptionView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *locationData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) DescriptionView *descriptionView;

@end
```

CaseViewController.m

```
- (void)loadView {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];

    descriptionView = [[DescriptionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 130, 320, 237)];
    descriptionView.hidden = NO;

    [view addSubview:descriptionView];

    self.view = view;
    [view release];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ideally you should never access any properties of viewcontroller from the view.
The main idea of MVC architecture is that viewcontroller tells it's views what to render and not vise versa.
  So you just have to provide all the data that your view needs for rendering during it's initialization:

```
- (void)loadView { 
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];

    descriptionView = [[DescriptionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 130, 320, 237) paramDict: self.locationData]; descriptionView.hidden = NO;

    [view addSubview:descriptionView];

    [descriptionView release]; // BTW add this line here (or in dealloc) or you'll have a leak

    self.view = view; [view release]; 
}
```

If you need to update your view dynamically, then you should add some methods to your view and call them from viewcolnroller. 
E.g.:

DescriptionView.m:

```
-(void) updateWithDict:(NSDictionary*) udict;
```

If you need to perform some actions when some button in DescriptionView is pressed (or any other user interaction) a good idea would be declaring a protocol like DescriptionViewDelegate (or smth like that):

```
-(void) descriptionViewButton1Pressed:(DescriptionView*) dview;
-(void) descriptionViewButton2Pressed:(DescriptionView*) dview;
```

then make your CaseViewController a delegate and implement that methods there.

Comment: Awesome - Thanks - You're absolutely right about not moving logic to the view :)

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest way to have a reference to its viewcontroller from a view is to extend `UIView`:

```
@interface MyView: UIView {
    UIViewController *mViewController;
}
```

Then in `loadView`

```
MyView *view = [[MyView alloc] init];
view.mViewController = self;
```